# how could i show the table row data as header in html

Tags: php, html, mysql

Here is the code for **HSHY.php** i wanted to show the table row content as the header on this homepage ,but it keep cannot retrieve the data from the connection file

```html
   
 <header>
        <h2><?php  echo $_SESSION['company']  ?></h2>
  <p>Current User: <?php echo $_SESSION["username"]; ?><a href="logout.php">[Logout]</a></p>
        
      
    </header>
```

Here is the **HSHYcon.php** after i have done the connection,i need to pass the table row data to the homepage as the header.(the data can be able to show on this php file)

```html
if (isset($_POST['HSHY'])){
$link_mssql = odbc_connect(HOST_HSHY,DB_USER,DB_PASS);
$company= '';
 $sql = "SELECT Name FROM CompanyProfile ";
  $rs = odbc_exec($link_mssql,$sql);
   while (odbc_fetch_row($rs)) {
       $company=odbc_result($rs,"Name");
  

       }
 $_SESSION['company']=$company;
header("location: HSHY.php");   // Redirecting To Other Page
  odbc_close($link_mssql); // Closing Connection
  //echo $company ;
 // Initializing Session
 


}
```

Comment: I hope that isn't your actual database password.

Comment: How you are passing the data to your home page?

Comment: Have you written session_start() at top of the page?